# Manage another Linux installation on another partition in the same computer

Tags: administration

How can I manage (install packages, manage packages, check for updates and the like) for another Linux installation on another partition in the same machine?

I would be doing this from Ubuntu, and the second could be Fedora or Debian. Is that a kind of remote administration too, but on the same computer? And it would not be a one time shot, but regular work.

Comment: Please give us some details on your partitioning scheme. If you simply have all other systems on their own, single partitions (`/etc`, `/usr` etc on the same partition) it is very easy to do with `chroot`.

Comment: Yes, I have each system complete in its own partition, even with its own swap.

Comment: In that case, my `chroot` suggestion should work for most use cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the simplest scenario where each distribution has its own partition and everything necessary for the system to run is within that partition (you don't have separate partitions for `/usr` for example), you can do this with [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root):

I assume you have the partitions mounted somewhere, let's say they're at `/Debian` and `/Fedora`. Set up a `chroot` environment:

```
sudo chroot /Debian
```

That will move you into `/Debian`, running a shell that thinks you are `root` and running the installed Debian system. At this point, you can use `apt-get` as you would normally. When you're done, you can return to your session by running `exit`.

This should work perfectly well for simple software management but I wouldn't run major updates or changes to important packages this way.

Comment: I think i miss interpreted some events on my system. I will follow your suggestion it would be useful for me if it works fine.
Here i remove all objections. and thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @Slyx you may have been thinking of `pivot_root`. that would fit the results you described.

Comment: @strugee : Strongly probable ! It was many years ago. I don't have a real elephant memory to confirm for sure :-)
I'll try both mechanisms soon and put a feedback.

Comment: @Slyx don't try them without reading the manpages. chroot is ok to play with but pivot_root is dangerous